# how 2D array pass in MPJ (other than object form)

Tags: java, mpi, daemon, mpj-express

I want to send adjacency matrix through MPJ, and one solution of that is to send the 2-d array  in the form of an object, and a second solution is to send the 2-d array as one-dimensional array, i.e. a[N*N].

However, I wish to send the 2-d array in its original form -- is it supported by MPJ? If so, how should I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite approach would be to send the 2D array as a 1D array of Objects, where each object is a 1D array.

For example, if you wish to send `int A[M][N]`, you can simply do

```
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(A, 0, M, MPI.OBJECT, TARGET_ID, MESSAGE_ID);
```

To receive, you can first create a buffer and then use MPI Receive:

```
int buffer[][] = new int[M][N];
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(buffer, 0, M, MPI.OBJECT, SENDER_ID, MESSAGE_ID);
```

Note that the offset and length in your MPI commands correspond to the index of the outer-most array.

Hope it helps!